# Replace given column's first row value with NaN for each group in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How can replace the first row's value of `pct` as `NaN` for each group `city` and `district`? Thank you.

```
  city district       date   pct
0    a        b   2019/8/1   0.15
1    a        b   2019/9/1   0.12
2    a        b  2019/10/1   0.25
3    c        d   2019/7/1   0.03
4    c        d   2019/8/1  -0.36
5    c        d   2019/9/1   0.57
```

I can only get the first row's `pct` value for dataframe by `df['pct'].iloc[0]`.

My desired output will like this:

```
  city district       date   pct
0    a        b   2019/8/1   NaN
1    a        b   2019/9/1   0.12
2    a        b  2019/10/1   0.25
3    c        d   2019/7/1   NaN
4    c        d   2019/8/1  -0.36
5    c        d   2019/9/1   0.57
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) + [`DataFrame.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html)

```
df['pct']=df['pct'].where(df.duplicated(subset = ['city','district']))
print(df)

  city district       date   pct
0    a        b   2019/8/1   NaN
1    a        b   2019/9/1   0.12
2    a        b  2019/10/1   0.25
3    c        d   2019/7/1   NaN
4    c        d   2019/8/1  -0.36
5    c        d   2019/9/1   0.57
```

---

**Detail:**

```
df.duplicated(subset = ['city','district'])


0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
5     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't under why use `df.duplicated` to realize this? Can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: So no need to `df['pct'].iloc[0]` for each group `city` and `district`?

Comment: no, because by default (see reference) `keep = 'first'`, then the first value for each district city pair becomes `False`

Comment: dataframe duplicated creates a boolean series with False in the first duplicate based on the columns indicated in subset, in this case city and district. We use this Series with `Series.where` to convert False values ​​to NaN